# Add css class to select_year helper in Rails (HAML)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to write this code

```
<select name="date[birth]" id="date_birth" class = "span1">
      <option value="2011">2011</option>
      <option value="2012" selected="selected">2012</option>
      <option value="2013">2013</option>
      </select>
```

in Rails, it has the select_year helper, I just write

```
= select_year(Date.today, :field_name => "birth", :start_year => 2011, :end_year => 2013)
```

I try to add css class to this by the attribute `:class => "span1"`, but it doesn't work!
Please help me, thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
= select_year(Date.today, {:field_name => "birth", :start_year => 2011, :end_year => 2013}, {:class => "span1"})
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes the answer is what @aromero provided. You need to add the `:class => "span1"` in a separate hash.

In case you have taken look at [**the function declaration**](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/select_year) and couldn't realize, Im trying to explain this.

the function definition is

```
select_year(date, options = {}, html_options = {})
```

See, its actually taking three parameters,

- **date:** the current date
- **options:** hash of parameters related to show the information
- **html_options:** hash of parameters related showing the html tag.

So in your case adding a class name is actually a part of `html_options`. So you need to separate these two hashes and add the `class_name` in last one.

This is important to realize because there are lots of rails helper that takes parameters in this way. And always refer to [**apidock.com/rails**](http://apidock.com/rails) or [**guides.rubyonrails.org**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org) for clear understandings of any api.